# How to parse dag_run.conf to a custom function using a custom operator

Tags: python, airflow

This is my current code:

```
def render_file_name(task_type, table_name):

    if 'cleanup' == task_type:
        file_name = f"path/to/{table_name}_his_full_cleanup.sql'
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown task type: {task_type}")

    return file_name

with DAG("load_data", template_searchpath=SCRIPTS_PATH) as dag:

    cleanup_sql = render_file_name(task_type='cleanup', table_name='{{ dag_run.conf["table_name"] }}')

    table_his_full_cleanup = MyCustomOperator(
    task_id="table_full_cleanup",
    name="table_full_cleanup",
    sql=cleanup_sql,
    parameters={
        "env": ENV,
        "temp_table_name": '{{ dag_run.conf["table_name"] }}_temp',
    },
    default_iam_role=IAM_ROLE,
    spark_cluster=MY_SPARK,
    )
```

I'm getting the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: path/to/{{ dag_run.conf["table_name"] }}_his_full_cleanup.sql

It seems that `sql` unable to take `dag_run.conf["table_name"]`
But `parameters` able to parse the value correctly. Why is that?

How do I solve this?
I can share the source code of `MyCustomOperator` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your entire DAG script but I wrote a sample DAG. it includes your function (with some dummy inputs). And it works:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def render_file_name(task_type, table_name):

    if 'cleanup' == task_type:
        file_name = "path/to/"+str(table_name)+"_his_full_cleanup.sql"
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown task type: {task_type}")
    return file_name

#this will show default value when you run w/Config
your_default_param = {'table_name': 'TABLE_NAME'}
table_name = "{{dag_run.conf['table_name']}}"

default_args = {
        'start_date': datetime(2023, 8, 17),
        'params' : your_default_param
        }

with DAG(dag_id="load_data", default_args=default_args) as dag:

    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    operation = PythonOperator(task_id="print", python_callable=render_file_name, op_kwargs={'task_type': 'cleanup', 'table_name': table_name})
    end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")

    start >> operation
    operation >> end
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: did you try to trigger DAG w/config? try trigger DAG w/config and add your table name there.

Comment: yes of course i did :)

Comment: i wrote a new answer. this one works :). probably your DAG scripts include some places which can't pass param values. try this one

Comment: @user6308605 did you try the code? if it's useful for you, please accept the answer